# Show Toast when sms message received using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to develop an app to notify me with a `Toast` when a sms message will received. By using `BroadcastReceiver` below is my code:

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Intent received: " + intent.getAction());

        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "new incoming message" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

and manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

the problem is neither `Log` nor `Toast` is showing. where is the problem and what should I do for it?

Comment: Please search on google for sms broadcast . You will solution for it :)

Comment: I had searched, but no useful results.

Comment: `telephony` needs to be capitalized in the `<receiver>`'s `<action>` in the manifest. `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`. Also, make sure you're handling permissions correctly if you're running on Marshmallow+. And be sure to run your `MainActivity` at least once after installation.

Comment: yes it works @MikeM. I feel idiot

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String TAG = SmsReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    public SmsReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get the data (SMS data) bound to intent


        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();    

        if (bundle != null) {
            // Retrieve the SMS Messages received
             Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
             SmsMessage msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            //YOUR TOAST
        }
 }
```

you can get details from `msgs`

And In Manifest file

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".broadcast.SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

working file in live app.
Hope this helps..

Answer (score -1):

I've been using the following code for my SMS receiver:

```
    <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver"
              android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: unfortunately not working